# Set callback payload type

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js

I have this composable:

```
export const useSubscription = <
  T extends keyof typeof subscriptions,
  V = T extends keyof typeof subscriptions
    ? (typeof subscriptions)[T]['__generatedSubscriptionInput']
    : never,
  R = T extends keyof typeof subscriptions
    ? (typeof subscriptions)[T]['__generatedSubscriptionOutput']
    : never
>(
  subscriptionString: T,
  variables: V,
  next: <T>(payload: T) => unknown
) => {
  let sub: any = null
  onMounted(() => {
    sub = API.graphql<GraphQLSubscription<R>>(
      graphqlOperation(subscriptions[subscriptionString], variables)
    ).subscribe({
      next: (data) => next<typeof data>(data),
    })
  })
  onUnmounted(() => {
    sub?.unsubscribe()
  })
}
```

The `data` has a type and i want to pass it somehow to its callback `next: <T>(payload: T) => unknown`

But this approach does not work

```
let subscription = useSubscription(
  'onUpdateGroup',
  {
    filter: {
      id: props.group.id,
    },
  },
  (data) => {
    
  }
)
```

[image]

Its not set, is it possible to "pass" the type?